# Will my Phottix Ares ii triggers work with Yongnuo YN 560 III speedlights?

Tags: off-camera-flash, hotshoe-flash, yongnuo, phottix

At the moment I’m using a Canon 100D. Will the Phottix Ares II transmitter and receiver work with a Yongnuo YN-560 III speedlite?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding IR / RF flash systems](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/72593/understanding-ir-rf-flash-systems)

Comment: See [The combination of transmitters to fire AND control Canon 430EX III-RT and Yongnuo YN-560 IV](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/96069/75526) and [How do I sync a Yongnuo YN560 III speedlight with a Canon 6D?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/100050/75526).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you attach the transmitter to your camera's hotshoe and the receiver to the foot of the flash, they will work to trigger the flash off-camera.  But you cannot use TTL, HSS, 2nd curtain, or control the power level of the flash from the transmitter. The Ares II are manual-only triggers. The Strobist recommends them for pro-level reliability, not for features. But if you're a hobbyist, maybe you'd prefer more features over reliability for your buck, since heavy-use reliability may never be required with only occasional light usage.

A possible better choice would be to get a Yongnuo YN-560-TX transmitter. This will work with the radio receiver that's built in to a YN-560 III, and will also allow you to remotely control the power level of the flash.

If you don't yet own the Yongnuo YN-560 III/IV/-660/-720, an even better choice for a low-cost manual off-camera flash combo might be to get a Godox TT600 and a Godox XPro-C (or X1T-C) transmitter, which will get you remote power control and HSS.  Well, at least at the time I'm writing this (summer 2018). Tech moves fast in the cheap Chinese flash world.

See also:

- [Are RF wireless triggers systems compatible with one another?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/40335)
- [What are the Yongnuo flash naming conventions?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/47702)
- [What features should one look for when selecting a flash?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/17722)