# Can a Yongnuo YN-560 III wireless flash be used with a Hahnel Combi TF (both for Nikon)?

Tags: flash, off-camera-flash, yongnuo, wireless-triggers

Can a Yongnuo YN-560 III wireless flash speedlite for a Nikon DSLR be used with a Hahnel Combi TF for Nikon?

Comment: What are you wanting to control remotely? The flash from the camera, or the camera from the flash?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are RF wireless triggers systems compatible with one another?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/40335/are-rf-wireless-triggers-systems-compatible-with-one-another) See also: [How compatible are different flash brands for remote control over the flash?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/85241)

Comment: Those possible duplicates assume the OP wants to trigger an off camera flash while physically operating the camera. That assumption is far from clear in the question, particularly since the Hahnel TF is marketed primarily as a way to remotely fire the camera without physically holding it.

Answer (score 1):

**For triggering the flash remotely from the camera:**

Only if you also have a Hahnel TF receiver attached to the hot foot of the YN560 III as well as a Hahnel TF transmitter attached to the camera's hot shoe. You'll only be able to tell the flash to *fire*. You will need to set the flash power and zoom head using the flash's own control panel.

The built-in radio receiver in the YN560 III is not compatible with the Hahnel TF radio protocol, and the Hahnel TF system is not compatible with the YN560/RF605/RF603 radio protocol.

If you want to use the built in radio receiver of the YN560 III, or if you want to control flash power and zoom of the remote flash from the camera, you need a transmitter that uses the YN560/RF605/RF603 protocol, such as the YN560-TX.

**For triggering the camera remotely with the flash attached to the camera's hot shoe:**

It will work, you just won't be able to place the receiver on the camera's hot shoe. The actual signal is communicated via a cable that plugs into the remote shutter release port. Some folks use velcro to attach such accessories to a camera body without tying up the hot shoe when communication via the hot shoe is not needed.